# How to use find and sed to replace certain sentences in files

Tags: linux, bash, sed, find

I am using `find` and `sed` commands to find and replaces the occurrences of certain sentences in the whole directory with some other sentences.

For example if I want to replace all occurrences of the sentence `He went` to `She goes` in all the files of a certain directory (`\home\user\`), I do the following:

```
find '/home/user' -type f | xargs sed -i  's/He went/She goes/g'
```

Now I want to do the above command but for several sentences. For that I have a tab separated file with the sentences that I want to replace on the LHS and the new sentences on the RHS.

For example

```
He went\tShe goes
<h1>They tried<\h1>\t<h2>They did not try<\h2>
```

Is there a way to modify the above command to accomdate for such tab separated file instead of taking the sentences manually?

Comment: If you have to search and replace xml, sed (and other text tools) will fail, sooner or later. Use an xml parser/editor.

Comment: @thanasisp it is a mix of searching and replacing JavaScript/HTML code and normal text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in a two-step process, whereby in the first phase, using the TAB-delimited table file, we generate a set of `grep` & `sed` commands , and store them in a different hierarchy so that `find` doesn't find them and hence modify them potentially.

```bsh
##1> generate commands
sed -E '
  h;s/.*\t//
  # escape characters special on rhs
  s:[\&/]:\\&:g

  # grep code
  x;s/\t.*//w/tmp/code.grep

  # lhs escaping
  s:[][$^.*\/]:\\&:g;G

  # stitch lhs rhs & form a s/// 
  s:^|\n|$:/:g;s/.*/s&g/

' file.cmds > /tmp/code.sed

##2> use the commands

find /home/user -type f \
  -exec grep -qF -f /tmp/code.grep {} \; \
  -exec sed -i -f /tmp/code.sed {} + ;
```

---

- You should place the dynamically generated code files in a different hierarchy than in which you are searching.
- The table file should use a literal TAB rather than its symbol `\t`  as during code generation it will be seen as two characters , a `backslash` followed by the alphabet `t`

Comment: What if the RHS is blank (replace LHSwith nothing/delete)?

Comment: Yes that is what it will do. If you intend some other operation then you may state it in the question statement .